# Angular 9 dynamic routes

Tags: angular, typescript

first of all sorry for my english i dont speak very well but I will try to explain myself!
I'm creating an eCommerce in Angular 9 and the routes of this eCommerce work as follows, every route that comes in the end with `.html` I direct to a component that I call router-redirects, when I fall into that component I call the ecommerce api passing the url in question then it returns if that url is a category, a product, an article.. with this answer I redirect to the right component.

The problem is that in certain situations like the categories page I need to leave some query strings like pageIndex and orderby in the URL but angular does not show the query strings because when I do the navigate I put `skipLocationChange: true` because I cannot change the url and I need to keep the queryString.

I only need this for when a user wants to share the url with someone else.

Example of how I am doing the navigate method:

```
this.router.navigate(['categoria-listagem'], {
      skipLocationChange: true,
      queryParams: { page: 1, order: 'novidades' }
});
```

Please if anyone knows a better way to do this redirection or know how to keep query strings even with skipLocationChange it would save me !!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @Guilherme - did you manage to fix your issue?

Comment: Hi, not yet.... I think i have to use a Guard to re-route insted of a component. If I manage to get it right I will post here!

Comment: I think router-redirects should be a service rather than a component, but it's hard to say without seeing more code. Generally, it sounds like quite a complicated approach to routing, but good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should add [queryParamsHandling](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#queryParamsHandling) as 'merge' or 'preserve' (depending on your requirements) e.g.

```
this.router.navigate(['categoria-listagem'], {
  skipLocationChange: true,
  queryParams: { page: 1, order: 'novidades' },  
  queryParamsHandling: "merge"
});
```

This should add your new query params to any already in your URL.

Also you may need to remove `skipLocationChange`, again depending on the functionality you need.